# How to call loadview() two or more times with DomPDF

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I want to load the same view using function `loadview()` multiple times to call an array with other data. I want to add first $pdf1 to second $pdf2.

```
$pdf = $pdf1 + $pdf2;
```

To pass all data of $pdf1 and $pdf2 to $pdf for sending to the view. Is there a way to do that?

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    error_log('Some message here.');
    if (!empty ($nbrrowsol)) {
        $pdf1 = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF',
            ['commandesol' => $commandesol, 'nbrrowsol' => $nbrrowsol])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    }

    if (!empty ($nbrroweau)) {
        $pdf2 = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF',
            ['commandeeau' => $commandeeau, 'nbrroweau' => $nbrroweau])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    }

    $pdf = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF', [
        'clients' => $clients, 'commercial' => $commercial, 'datereception' => $datereception,
        'dateprelevement' => $dateprelevement
    ])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');

    return $pdf->stream('hdtuto.pdf');//redirect('gestion_commandes/create'); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    error_log('Some message here.');
    if (!empty ($nbrrowsol)) {
        $pdf1 = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF',
            ['commandesol' => $commandesol, 'nbrrowsol' => $nbrrowsol])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
 return $pdf1->stream('hdtuto.pdf');//redirect('gestion_commandes/create'); 
}
    }

    if (!empty ($nbrroweau)) {
        $pdf2 = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF',
            ['commandeeau' => $commandeeau, 'nbrroweau' => $nbrroweau])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
 return $pdf2->stream('hdtuto.pdf');//redirect('gestion_commandes/create'); 
}
else{
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('gestion_commandes.myPDF', [
        'clients' => $clients, 'commercial' => $commercial, 'datereception' => $datereception,
        'dateprelevement' => $dateprelevement
    ])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('hdtuto.pdf');//redirect('gestion_commandes/create'); 
}
}
```